# Calculated Field withMultiple If

Tags: sql

I am struggling to create a calculated field within my SQL query.

The query reports some statistics and Column E has a figure taken from the database, let's call it "Contract Award Value".

Based on that figure I need to calculate a fee that we will be charging. We used excel previously with the following function:

`=IF(E1<100000,2500+E1*0.005,IF(E1<1000000,5000+E1*0.005,IF(E1>=1000000,7500+E1*0.005)))`

Is there any chance to add a line in SQL that will calculate how much we need to charge based on the formula above? For clarity, if E1 is less than £100k, the charge is £2,500 + 0.5%; If between £100k and £1m, the charge is £5,000 + 0.5%; If over £1,000,000, the charge is £10,000 + 0.5%.

I tried to look for the answer in similar topics but did not find anything that could help.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: ***Try*** to write the SQL and show us.Make an effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL, you would express this using a `case` expression:

```
(case when E1 < 100000 then 2500 + E1 * 0.005
      when E1 < 1000000 then 5000 + E1 * 0.005
      when E1 >= 1000000 then 7500 + E1 * 0.005
 end) as fee
```

This assumes that `E1` is a column in your data.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed! That helped!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function which will give you expected result and you can call that function in your query